# prints the string with enough leading spaces?

Tags: python, function

Python provides a built-in function called len that returns the length of a string, so the value of `len('allen')` is `5`.

Write a function named `right_justify` that takes a string named `s` as a parameter and prints the string with enough leading spaces so that the last letter of the string is in column 70 of the display.

```
>>> right_justify('allen')
                                                       allen
```

I solved it like this:

```
def right_justify(s):
    print "                                                                 " + s    

right_justify('allen')
```

Is it right?

Are there built-in Python methods to do what I need to do?

Comment: have a look at [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: Python strings actually have two built-in methods on the string object directly. `rjust` and `ljust` doing exactly what you would expect, right justify and left justify respectively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its quite easy with [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
def right_justify(s):
    print "%70s" % s
```

Comment: How can I align it to the left instead of right? @Jochen Ritzel

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, there's a neat little trick you can apply here:

```
def right_justify(s, total_length=70):
    return ' ' * (total_length - len(s)) + s
```

In case it's not perfectly clear, this'll print out total_length - length of s blankspaces.

Comment: First of all, I prefer Jochen Ritzel's solution, it's cleaner than mine. But the reason you don't get any output is that this function _returns_ your value. [Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement) is a very fundamental statement in all computer programming, and I'd suggest you'd experiment a bit with it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
In [60]: strs="allen"

In [61]: format(strs,">70s")
Out[61]: '                                                                 allen'

In [62]: format(strs,">70s").index('n')
Out[62]: 69
```

or using [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
In [68]: "{0:>70s}".format(strs)
Out[68]: '                                                                 allen'
```

Comment: I am new with python, so you solution make me confused a little , sorry but didn't understand what you wrote up

Comment: @BassamBadr this is simple string formatting, see my comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
def right_justify(s):
    print len(s)
    print ' '* (70 - len(s)) + s

word = raw_input('enter any word')
right_justify(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def right_justify(s):
    print ('')
    print ('Number of chars: ' + str(len(s)))
    print ('')
    print (' '* (70 - len(s)) + s)

word = input('Enter any word: ')
right_justify(word)
```

Comment: Please stick to English here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I won't do your homework for you, but here is a simple algorithm:

1. Find out how long your string is (hint: `len()`).
2. Find out how many spaces you need to print (hint: if your string is 5 characters and the total length should be 70, you want to print 65 spaces).
3. Print the spaces.
4. Print the string.

Comment: It isn't homework, it just a question from here http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/book004.html
thank you anyway

Comment: I assume @Tim was trying to avoid using the built-in methods on the assumption that avoiding them was part of the requirements of a homework assignment (as is often the case). That is the only case where reinventing a built-in method makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
     def right_justify(s):
         print((70-len(s))*' '+s)
```

Comment: When you provide code, you should also provide explanation so the person who asked the question knows what was wrong, what you did, and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
def right_justify(s):
    length=len(s)
    spaces=70-length
    print ((' ' * spaces) + s)

right_justify('allen')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def right_justify (s):
    x = ' '
    w = (70-len(s))*x + s
    print (w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misread the question, but it seems like the answers that have been given only give the correct result if the variable is one character long. 
I am also really new to coding so this may be way off base.

```
def right_justify(s):
        length = len(s)
        adjustedLength = len(s) -1
        spaces = 70 - length + adjustedLength
        print(spaces * " " + "s")


s = "whatever you want to enter"
right_justify(s)
```

I did this so no matter what s is defined as, you get 69 spaces and then "s".

If this is wrong, let me know so I can adjust my way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
def right_justify(s):
    length =len(s)
    spaces = 70-length
    print((" " * spaces) + s)

word = "monty"
right_justify(word)
```

after definition the length depends on the word chosen, not to the (s)... so you create the formula. length, spaces and print should be indented.
A variable must be invented so the word can be converted from str to variable format.

Comment: What if `s` is longer than 70 characters? It's better to use built-in formatting functions than to re-implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
    def right_justify(s):

    length = len('s')

    spaces = 70 - length 
    print "required space is",spaces

    print(" " * spaces) + s

right_justify('allen')
```

Output

```
required  space is  69
                                                                     allen
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like this, one of the many simple ways to do it:

```
def right_just(s):    
    print(s.rjust(70))

right_just('allen')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of yet another way to make it more dynamic :)

## Function

def right_justify(s,num):

```
print(s.rjust(num))
```

## Call Function

right_justify("Allen",50)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the last letter to appear in column 70, you need to subtract the length of `s` from 70, like so

```
def right_justify(s):
    print(" " * (70 - (len(s)) + s)
```